# "Dont' keep activities" mode: Activity is not destroying on tap Home (only on Samsung S6 7.0)

Tags: android, ondestroy, samsung-galaxy, onsaveinstancestate

I'm testing application in "Dont' keep activities" mode.

Flow  is the next: I'm tapping HOME, app moves  to background, then i'm  pressing its icon on  homescreen. On  all devices  this  flow  works  correclty: activity  destroying and onSaveInstanceState calling.

But only on Samsung  S6 Android 7.0  it has  unexpected behavoiur - activity not destroying and onSaveInstanceState not calling, so  by  tapping  on app icon  opens  the same activity and no data in  savedInstanceState bundle.

How to avoid this unexpected  behaviour? Need the same  behaviour on all devices

Comment: if Activity is not destroyed, your data should already be there. Why you need a call to onSaveInstanceState at all costs?

Comment: due to security reasons. I need to unlock the application  with pin  after each its restoring from  background. I'm showing fragment  with  pin after destroyng -new creating the activity. So in  case  with Samsung 6 pin screen  not  shpwing  and  app works incorrectly

Comment: If for "restoring from background" you mean after an onPause and a call to onResume. You could set a property to false in onPause and check its value in onResume. If false the app is resuming from background and you can show your pin fragment.

Comment: @MatPag thank you so much, it helped